# SAPUI5 binding a value of a dropdownbox to an attribute of another control

Tags: xml, view, sapui5

Im new to sapui5 and im trying to set the visibility of a textarea based on the selected item/key of a dropdownbox in an expressing binding

part of my view:

```
   <DropdownBox id="cboId" editable="true" rows="50" cols="50" />
    <TextArea id="areaId" visible="{= ${#cboId}.getSelectedKey() === 1 }" />
```

I know the syntax is not right, but it give a clue how i would like to use the binding.

Is it even possible to bind a selection in the xml view?

Answer (score 1):

Just add an eventhandler to the change event of the DropdownBox.

XML:

```
<DropdownBox id="cboId" editable="true" rows="50" cols="50" change= "eventhandler"/>
    <TextArea id="areaId" />
```

Eventhandler in the controller:

```
eventhandler : function({
this.getView().byId("areaId").setVisible(
     this.getView().byId("cboId").getSelectedKey() === 1)
)
}
```

Comment: thanks for your effort, but this is the straight forward solution and i wanted to avoid writing eventhandlers for "simple" tasks like this

Comment: Could have mentioned that in the question then ;)